# Devise error when creating a new user with username and roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Alright so I’m building an app using Rails 7, Devise, and Rolify. I want to start using Friendly ID to create the URL slugs for my different database tables. I’m applying this to the user table first so I’m adding the username column to the User table. I was able to successfully add the username string to the existing user records I had and I was able to update my User model with the proper syntax to view the users with their friendly ID URL slug based on the username.

I’m running into an error when creating a new user.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `for' for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x00007fc11795a7b0 @auth_keys=[:email], @params=#<ActionController::Parameters {"authenticity_token"=>"bhh5F5BA1ERwI22Trejc1NvudieV9akyOtzS69kAi4Za6sRFpYB65OseiLWBSelfMkS-AAHld-vhDeSX7cMWbQ", "user"=>{"username"=>"bootyman", "email"=>"bootyman@gmail.com", "role_ids"=>["", "3"], "password"=>"password", "password_confirmation"=>"password"}, "commit"=>"Sign up", "controller"=>"devise/registrations", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>, @resource_name=:user, @permitted={:sign_in=>[:email, :password, :remember_me], :sign_up=>[:email, :password, :password_confirmation], :account_update=>[:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password]}>):
22:42:42 web.1  |
22:42:42 web.1  | app/controllers/application_controller.rb:10:in `configure_permitted_parameters'
```

Based on some research on the Devise gem GitHub page I found some things that pointed to adding some code to the `application_controller.rb`

Here's my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :html, :json
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end
    def require_user
        unless user_signed_in?
          flash[:alert] = "You must be logged in to perform that action"
          redirect_to new_user_session_path
        end
      end
end
```

Here's my User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :artists, dependent: :destroy
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  validates :email, presence: true,
         uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
         length: { maximum: 105 },
         format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }
  validates :password, :presence => true, :on => :create
  validates :username, :presence => true, :on => :create
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, case_sensitive: false 
  validates :roles, presence: true

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: :slugged

  def admin?
    self.has_role?(:Admin)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found on GitHub that the `.for` method was deprecated and the replacement code in the `devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb` for the method is

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
end
```

To access this file you need to run `bundle open devise` to access the gem files for Devise.

Reference [link](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise-pundit/issues/33)